# Rspec undefined model method test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec, undefined

The answer to this is probably obvious to someone that isn't new to Rspec testing like me. I am just trying to test a method defined in a model but every time I run the spec it gives me a undefined method error. Below are the details:

Model method trying to test:

```
def auto_respond(behaviors)
. . . 
end
```

My spec/models/message_spec.rb test for this method:

```
RSpec.describe Message, :type => :model do
describe "auto_respond(behaviors)" do
let!(:good_response) { create(:good_response) }
let!(:good_survey_behavior) { create(:good_survey) }
let!(:bad_survey_behavior) { create(:bad_survey) }

context "when customer responds with a 5" do
  it "should be a valid matching pattern" do
    expect(auto_respond(good_survey)).to be_truthy
  end
end
end
end
```

The fail message:

```
1) Message auto_respond(behaviors) when customer responses with a 5 should be a valid matching pattern
 Failure/Error: expect(auto_respond(good_survey)).to be_truthy
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `auto_respond' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Message::AutoRespondBehaviors::WhenCustomerResponsesWithA5:0x007fdb8a756738>
 # ./spec/models/message_spec.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have other tests in the same spec file testing other methods in the same model with no problem. I have searched all over this site and other resources with no luck. Any direction or constructive criticism will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a instance method so you need to call it on instance of that model class.
By default rspec trying to run it on specs and thus throwing error as rspec has no method like auto_respond.

Comment: Got it. The test moved forward after I called it on an instance of the model class. Thanks so much!